# How to fix flutter doctor error android studio not installed, and IntelliJ IDEA, even though I've installed it already

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, android-studio, intellij-idea, flutter-doctor

I'm a beginner at learning flutter. I've installed Android Studio and flutter. I ran the command `flutter --version` on Windows Powershell and the output I received is `Flutter 2.2.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git Framework • revision f4abaa0735 (2 months ago) • 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700 Engine • revision 241c87ad80 Tools • Dart 2.13.4`
The next command I ran was `flutter doctor` and I received output as:

```
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1165], locale en-IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    X Cannot execute C:\Users\lenovo\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1\bin\java to determine the version
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Can anyone please help me in fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue on Windows. This does not seem to happen on Linux (Ubuntu) for me.
But it's a warning you can ignore. Even if Flutter Doctor does not recognize Android Studio, you can still use it in Android Studio if everything else is set up.